# What is the correct way to TRY to Response.Redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

I want to redirect to a url, but be informed if it fails.

As far as I know a simple try-catch block won't work here because a Redirect *always* throws an exception. Although I can check for that exception  (ThreadAbortException), but is this the best way?

EDIT: I'm trying to Redirect to a certain url, and if it doesn't exist - to another url.

Comment: You do not redirect if its fails, and you show a message. You mean if fails to redirect ? you do not know well the destination url ? what ?

Comment: @Aristos That's my question - _how_ am I informed that it failed. - I mean - how is _the program_ informed.

Comment: If its so critical that you need to know, then you need to add signaling on the destination url. If you care just to know if the destination url exist, then you simple check it out before redirect with a url call from code behind.

Comment: What do you mean "redirect fails"? Redirect is simply special response with code 302 and `location` header - there is no built in way for server to know if client follows redirect or not... (You have answer about not throwing `ThreadAbortException`, but it only helps with number of exeptions thrown, not if redirect fails/succeeds...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since redirect is client side operation (server simply sends response with code 302 and header `location` set to redirect destination) you can't expect server side `Request.Redirect` call to give you any indications if redirect succeeds on client (or even if it will be followed).

You options:

- just live with that
- if redirect is local you can at least verify if local path exists (or if ysing MVC - if route with given parameters is defined).
- if redirect is remote you can try to issue request on the server first and see if response is reasonable (like "not 404").

Unfortunately all server side options to see if destination page exist have serious drawbacks:

- checking for Url is potentially slow operation
- you will not be albe to pass authentication information/cookes to pages on remote locations
- some servers respond with 200 for "page really does not exist, look somewhere else".

Comment: Thanks. Please correct me if I'm wrong - checking if the file exists might run into permission issues even in a local context (It's on a web hosting service), and since I _do_ need to know - I'm left with the option to send a request and see if it fails. (I'll be able to know by checking how my web-host manages that)

Comment: @ispiro, yes. Note that with checking for existance of files you likly to run into reverse problem too - locally code is able to access more files than over HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this code will win a prize, but this at least prevents the ThreadAbortException...

Inspired by the [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629)

```
bool redirectOK = false;
try
{
  Repsonse.Redirect(url, false);
  redirectOK = true;
}
catch(Exception exp)
{
   // log/handle/whatever
}
if (redirectOK)
{
 // do what even you want for a serverside succeeded redirect
}
else
{
  // do what ever you want for a failure to redirect
}
```

Comment: +1. Note that not throwing exception will let other code on the page to finish execution - make sure you do not perform any operations after Redirect (i.e. I believe you can even remove redirect by calling `Resposnse.Clear()` after `Respose.Redirect(url, false)`).

Comment: I just tried redirecting with a "false" to a nonexistent url, (running in Visual Web Developer on localhost) and the browser shows me "The resource cannot be found"  even though I have an empty `catch` after the Redirect in a `try`.

Comment: You can only detect serverside errors, if you redirect to something non-existent only the browser will know...from the Redirect point of view it is fine to Redirect("/non-existing-page/foo.html") assuming the client is still connected (hence the HTTP headers got sent to the client)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this will check for a 404 error, then direct to the page if there is no error.

```
if URLExists(theURL){
Response.Redirect(theUrl);
}
else{
//redirect somewhere else
}


public static bool UrlExists(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                if (url == "")
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(url);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        return false;
                    else
                        throw;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```